# Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: [ng] Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

[ng] Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
[ng]   Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

```
    The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

npm update --all --force